# Can't send an email via E-mail client for Postfix/Dovecot

Tags: postfix, dovecot, thunderbird

On my server with Postfix, Dovecot and Postgresql I can receive email flawsly, but not send them. 
Via Thunderbird.

When trying to send it, I see this in the logs of Postfix:

```
  postfix/qmgr[14391]: B63131F952: from=<>, size=2376, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
  postfix/smtp[15967]: connect to fdsafds.com[11.22.33.44]:25: Connection timed out
  postfix/smtp[15967]: B63131F952: to=<fdsafds@fdsafds.com>, relay=none, delay=412770, delays=412739/0.03/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to fdsafds.com[11.22.33.44]:25: Connection timed out)
  postfix/submission/smtpd[15973]: connect from unknown[33.44.55.66]
  postfix/submission/smtpd[15973]: warning: connect #1 to subsystem public/submission-header-cleanup: No such file or directory
  postfix/submission/smtpd[15973]: warning: connect #2 to subsystem public/submission-header-cleanup: No such file or directory
  postfix/submission/smtpd[15973]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem public/submission-header-cleanup: No such file or directory
  postfix/submission/smtpd[15973]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem public/submission-header-cleanup: No such file or directory
  postfix/master[14389]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/bin/smtpd pid 15973 exit status 1
  postfix/master[14389]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/bin/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
  postfix/anvil[15975]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (submission:33.44.55.66) at Jun  1 03:34:19
  postfix/anvil[15975]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (submission:33.44.55.66) at Jun  1 03:34:19
  postfix/anvil[15975]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jun  1 03:34:19
```

What can be a cause?

```
  $ sudo postconf -M
  smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
  cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
  qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
  tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
  rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
  bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
  defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
  trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
  verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
  flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
  proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
  proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
  smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
  relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
  showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
  error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
  retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
  discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
  local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
  virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
  lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
  anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
  scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
  smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
  submission inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING -o smtpd_helo_required=no -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= -o cleanup_service_name=submission-header-cleanup
```

And

```
    $ sudo postconf -n 
    alias_database =
    alias_maps =
    allow_percent_hack = no
    biff = no
    command_directory = /usr/bin
    compatibility_level = 2
    daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/bin
    data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
    debug_peer_level = 2
    debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
    disable_vrfy_command = yes
    home_mailbox = Maildir/
    html_directory = no
    inet_interfaces = all
    inet_protocols = ipv4
    mail_owner = postfix
    mail_spool_directory = /var/mail/local
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
    manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
    message_size_limit = 51200000
    meta_directory = /etc/postfix
    mydestination = $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
    mydomain = my_domain123.com
    myhostname = mail.my_domain123.com
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
    myorigin = $mydomain
    newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
    queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
    readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
    recipient_delimiter = +
    sample_directory = /etc/postfix
    sendmail_path = /usr/bin/sendmail
    setgid_group = postdrop
    shlib_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
    show_user_unknown_table_name = no
    smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
    smtp_tls_security_level = dane
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_tlscache
    smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname, reject_unauth_pipelining
    smtpd_data_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_multi_recipient_bounce, reject_unauth_pipelining
    smtpd_helo_required = yes
    smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unauth_pipelining
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining
    smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
    smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
    smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
    smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
    smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining
    smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
    smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.my_domain123.com/fullchain.pem
    smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh2048.pem
    smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh512.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.my_domain123.com/privkey.pem
    smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
    smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
    smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
    smtpd_tls_security_level = may
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_tlscache
    strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
    swap_bangpath = no
    tls_high_cipherlist = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    tls_ssl_options = no_ticket, no_compression
    unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
    virtual_alias_domains =
    virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
    virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
    virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

**Note** that for receiving emails I have to use SSL/TLS in the settings of my Thunderbird, whereas for sending when I'm using  SSL/TLS it won't connect. When I'm trying to send an email and using STARTTLS it at least connects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking a your submission service with `cleanup_service_name=submission-header-cleanup`. However, you don't have any service named `submission-header-cleanup` configured.

Either remove `-o cleanup_service_name=submission-header-cleanup` from your `master.cf` (the default `cleanup_service` is `cleanup` and will take effect if you remove this override) or configure a `submission-header-cleanup` service.

Comment: which option do you recommend?

Comment: Since you're asking, removing the override.